# How do I access any particular field from my serializer.py file?

Tags: django, serialization, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm making an API for a webhook. I'm having an issue when I try to access only one field from my Class Message in models.py.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from django_hstore import hstore


class WebhookTransaction(models.Model):
    UNPROCESSED = 1
    PROCESSED = 2
    ERROR = 3

    STATUSES = (
        (UNPROCESSED, 'Unprocessed'),
        (PROCESSED, 'Processed'),
        (ERROR, 'Error'),
    )

    date_generated = models.DateTimeField()
    date_received = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    body = hstore.SerializedDictionaryField()
    request_meta = hstore.SerializedDictionaryField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=STATUSES, default=UNPROCESSED)

    objects = hstore.HStoreManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{0}'.format(self.date_event_generated)


class Message(models.Model):
    team_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    team_domain = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    channel_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    channel_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    text = models.TextField()
    trigger_word = models.CharField(max_length=250)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'{}'.format(self.user_name)
```

serializer.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from slack.models import WebhookTransaction, Message


class WebhookTransactionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = WebhookTransaction
        fields = '_all__'



class MessageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['team_id']
```

Now when I try to access only 'team_id' from the models It's giving me this error

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "slack_message" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "slack_message" ("team_id", "team_domain", "chan...
                    ^
```

Now my question is do I have to pass all the field for this to work? 
IF NOT then how can I access only one field from the list?

To give you more insights here are my views.py code

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from django.http import HttpResponse, JsonResponse
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from slack.models import WebhookTransaction
from slack.serializers import WebhookTransactionSerializer
from slack.models import Message
from slack.serializers import MessageSerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
import requests



class DRSWebhookTransactionView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            webhooktransaction = WebhookTransaction.objects.all()
            serializer = WebhookTransactionSerializer(webhooktransaction, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = WebhookTransactionSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)


class DRSMessageView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            message = Message.objects.all()
            serializer = MessageSerializer(message, many=True)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)

        elif request.method == 'POST':
            data = JSONParser().parse(request)
            serializer = MessageSerializer(data=data)
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return JsonResponse(serializer.data, status=201)
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

Can you take a look and tell what is it I'm doing wrong here?
Also try to explain how things works in the backend

Comment: Did you try `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands first? The Error says there is no such table called `slack_message`.

Comment: Can you double check in your DB whether you have this table or not?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now I'm having another issue.

Comment: But it will work, right? If I try to run only one field from a list?

Comment: It should work. Also in your views you don't require to compare `request.method=='GET'`. Since it is already a post request, you won't be able to reach inside this condition.